# Kubeflow Pipeline SDK Installation Error on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, kubeflow

I'm having some issues installing Kubeflow pipeline in Ubuntu 20.04. I have the following command that results in this error as below:

```
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~$ pip3 install kfp --upgrade --user
Collecting kfp
  Using cached kfp-1.8.12.tar.gz (301 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-fqahhk9w/kfp_36467ff13e1243d3a619915d5793d010/setup.py", line 154, in <module>
          'kfp=kfp.__main__:main'
        File "/home/joesan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 143, in setup
          _install_setup_requires(attrs)
        File "/home/joesan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 132, in _install_setup_requires
          (k, v) for k, v in attrs.items()
        File "/home/joesan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 426, in __init__
          k: v for k, v in attrs.items()
        File "/home/joesan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 292, in __init__
          self.finalize_options()
        File "/home/joesan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 716, in finalize_options
          for ep in sorted(eps, key=by_order):
        File "/home/joesan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 715, in <lambda>
          eps = map(lambda e: e.load(), pkg_resources.iter_entry_points(group))
        File "/home/joesan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2461, in load
          self.require(*args, **kwargs)
        File "/home/joesan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2484, in require
          items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
        File "/home/joesan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 792, in resolve
          raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
      pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (pyparsing 3.0.6 (/home/joesan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pyparsing<3,>=2.0.2'), {'packaging'})
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Any idea as to what this error points to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but this helped me solve this acute problem:

```
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```

And then I did the:

```
pip3 install kfp --upgrade --user
```